# How to create a T-SQL stored procedure for calculating average Run Time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with 318 record. Here is an example of the information contained in the table.

```
select * from TableName
```

output:

```
TestSequence     RunTime     TestName    
     1             12.00       Shark
     1             12.01       Shark
     1             13.02       Shark
     2             15.02       Lion
     2             10.13       Lion
     2             16.03       Lion
     3             18.02       pig
     3             12.58       pig
     3             17.00       pig
     4             14.69       Bird
     4             15.96       Bird
     4             16.32       Bird
```

As you can see that each TestName has 3 entries in the table with different run times. So what I want is to calculate the average RunTime for each TestName.

Here is the result am expecting:

```
TestSequence  TestName AverageRunTime
   1           Shark       12.50
   2           Lion        13.26
   3           pig         12.56
   4           Bird        15.36
```

I want a stored procedure to be able to calculate the average runtime for all the 318 rows in my table. I have never created a stored procedure in my life as am still fresh from university.

I am trying to build a stored procedure as shown below:

```
USE [DBName];  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime   
    @TestName varchar(50),   
    @TestSenquence varchar(50),
    @RunTime varchar(50)   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT TestName, TestSequence, AVG(RunTime) 
    FROM TableName
    WHERE TestSequence = @TestSenquence
    Group By TestName, TestSequence;


GO
```

Is there any other way of doing what am looking for?

Comment: [Group By](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx) ?

Comment: Will this stored procedure be run against the same table every time or is this going to be something that will need to be dynamic

Comment: yes it will be run against the same table everytime

Comment: Why is this a stored procedure?  Why not a view?  I'd also consider a name like GetTablenameAverageRuntime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows in the table, then remove the `where` clause.  The stored procedure would look more like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test_CalculateAverageRunTime  ()
AS 
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT TestName, TestSequence, AVG(RunTime) as avg_RunTime
    FROM TableName
    Group By TestName, TestSequence;
END;
```

However, I think an in-line table valued function may be more appropriate:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Test_CalculateAverageRunTime  ()
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN( SELECT TestName, TestSequence, AVG(RunTime) as avg_RunTime
        FROM TableName
        Group By TestName, TestSequence
      );
```

Then you can use the results in a query.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
SELECT TestName, TestSequence, AVG(RunTime) 
FROM TableName
WHERE TestSequence = @TestSenquence
GROUP BY TestName, TestSequence
```

You need `GROUP BY` if you are using an aggregate function such as AVG. You only need to have `@TestSenquence` as a parameter. The rest of your script is fine.

The stored procedure will always be run against the table named in the `FROM` clause. If you want to change then table name dynamically then that is a whole different area.

This is the best solution. What you require is to run a script with a variable/parameter to determine the output => a stored procedure is the way ahead. The other way would be to create a table valued function but that would be overkill.

Comment: Peter smith, sure I missed the group by clause when I pasted the code here. I have modified my code above

Comment: So, what's the problem with what you have?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this the best way to do it, thats why I had to ask